# Add element to NamedTuple

Tags: julia

I have written a function that adds an element to a NamedTuple:

```
function Base.setindex!(nt::NamedTuple, key::String, value::Any)
    return (; nt..., key=value)
end

nt = (; a=1, b=2)
setindex!(nt, "c", 3)
```

The issue is though that the added value has the key "key", and not the actual string that `key` represents as seen below:

> (a = 1, b = 2, key = 3)

How can I "evaluate" the `key`-variable before adding it to the NamedTuple?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it (note that this creates a new `NamedTuple` and does not update the passed `nt` as this is not possible):

```
julia> setindex(nt::NamedTuple, key::AbstractString, value) =
           merge(nt, (Symbol(key) => value,))
setindex (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> setindex((a=1, b=2), "c", 3)
(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)

julia> setindex((a=1, b=2), "b", 3) # note what happens if you re-use the key that is already present
(a = 1, b = 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try `using Accessors`. This is a Julia package providing a macro based syntax for working with immutable types. This syntax makes the code more readable.

```
julia> using Accessors

julia> nt = (;a=1, b=2)
(a = 1, b = 2)

julia> new_nt = @set nt.a = 33
(a = 33, b = 2)

julia> new_nt = @insert new_nt.c = 44
(a = 33, b = 2, c = 44)
```